# How to hold the dynamic text box and its values after form submission fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am using three dynamic textboxes in a form ,my problem is that when the form validation fails then i have to keep the user in that form ,Now my problem is that i  have to hold the values and those textbox also in the form ,how this is possible ?? i am giving a fiddle please suggest what can be done,

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/08uq09cL/1/)

Here is the fiddle

```
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
   return '<input class="txt1" name="DynamicTextBox" type="text" value="' + value + '" />&nbsp;<input class="txt2 time" id="myPicker" class="time" type="text" />&nbsp;<input name="phoneNum1" id="phoneNum1" class="time txt3"  type="text" /><input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" />';
}
```

This is the code which is responsible for the creating dynamic textboxes

Comment: In first case you will be creating duplicate `id` after first `add` which is invalid.. `id` has to be unique

Comment: Can you edit my fiddle i have created a working one??

Comment: Your **fiddle** neither have any `form` nor `submit` button... So try to post complete problem `fiddle`..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao how i can create form and submit  function in fiddle suggest me please

Comment: You just need to post complete `html`,`js` and `css`[if required] in fiddle in their corresponding section..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao but i  just need to hold the values if i post can you edit it??